# Mysql database help with tables

Tags: mysql, database

I've been trying to sort out a mysql query all day :( any help would be great.

I'm trying to relate three things.  menu items, groups of menu items and privilege levels.

So I have five tables:

A menuItems table with 
id (unique)

I have a group table
group id (unique)

and a menuIdGroupId table
groupId
menuId

I have a privilege table
privilegeid (unique)

and a groupsPrivlstable
idGroups 
idPrivilege

The privilege table and group table are really only lists of groups and privileges.  The privilegegroup table and the groupMenu table are both meant to be joining tables to relate everything.

I've tried a lot of combinations for the query and none work:

```
SELECT *
    FROM `menuIdGroupId`
       JOIN `menuItems` ON menuItems.id = menuIdGroupId.menuId
       JOIN `groupsPrivls` ON groupsPrivls.idGroups = menuIdGroupId.groupId
    WHERE groupsPrivls.idPrivilege = '1'
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

if groupsPrivls is

```
idGroups   idPrivilege
7          0
7          1
1          1
1          2
1          4
13         5
9          2
12         1
1          5
1          6
7          2
7          4
7          5
7          6
```

and menuIDGroupId

```
groupId   menuId
1         30
7         29
1         31
1         29
1         33
7         33
4         33
1         32
7         30
7         31

id     text
33     button 3     
32     button 2     
31     button 1     
30     Church   
29     About
```

Result is

```
groupId   menuId    id    text           idGroups     idPrivilege
7         29        29    About Us       7            1
7         33        33    button 3       7            1
7         30        30    New to Church  7            1
7         31        31    button 1       7            1
1         30        30    New to Church  1            1
1         31        31    button 1       1            1
1         29        29    About Us       1            1
1         33        33    button 3       1            1
1         32        32    button 2       1            1
```

As you can see I'm getting duplicate entries and I don't understand why.  I'm guessing I've not set it up eight.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Alan

PS sorry the format is so messy!

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental problem here: a bad model. Both things that you are interested in modeling (together) are *trees*. I would encourage you to look at either adjacency trees or nested set trees. That is assuming that you want menu items that have menu items inside, and likewise for the groups.

Another way to skin this would be to just model both as Composites. Doing so in a database involves using inheritance, but in these cases, it would be very simple.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm afraid my mysql isn't up to trees and composites.  I can do basic tables and some joins.  I had hoped that It would be possible to figure out the menuItems given an idPrivilege since the menuItems are unique.  I could parse it in PHP but my concern is that of a fndemental flaw that will be bad news further down the line.

Comment: The answer seems to be to use the GROUP BY function

Comment: Post your final query and answer the question yourself. I am pretty sure it might give you the result you can use, but it will not be capable of doing any nesting.